# How to use segmented package when working with data frames with dplyr package to perform piecewise linear regression?

Tags: r, dplyr, linear-regression, segment, piecewise

My data frame is separated by groups. I want to perform piecewise linear regression on each group and for that I intend to use the `segmented` package.

First I created the linear models for each group using the `dplyr` package. The next step is to segment these models, however this is where I'm stuck. Any tips or other way to do this? The ultimate goal is to use these segments to make a graph.

```
library(dplyr)
library(segmented)

Group <- c("A", "B")
x <- 0:10
y <- c(0, 0.4, 0.6, 0.8, 0.9, 0.9, 0.95, 0.97, 0.98, 0.99, 1,
       0, 0.01, 0.02, 0.03, 0.04, 0.05, 0.06, 0.07, 0.08, 0.09, 0.1)

df <- expand.grid(x = x,
                  Group = Group)

df$y <- y

Segment <- df %>%
  group_by(Group) %>%
  do(my.lm = lm(data = .,
                formula = y ~ x))
```

##### Unsuccessful attempts:

```
Segment <- df %>%
  group_by(Group) %>%
  do(my.lm = lm(data = .,
                formula = y ~ x),
     my.seg = segmented(my.lm,
                        seg.Z = x))


Segment <- df %>%
  group_by(Group) %>%
  do(my.lm = lm(data = .,
                formula = y ~ x)) %>%
  do(my.seg = segmented(my.lm,
                        seg.Z = x))


Segment <- df %>%
  group_by(Group) %>%
  do(my.lm = lm(data = .,
                formula = y ~ x)) %>%
  mutate(my.seg = segmented(my.lm,
                        seg.Z = x))
```

Comment: I think your dta is also not correct.  For eg. for the second group 'B', it will throw errors `Error in lm.fit(x, y, offset = offset, singular.ok = singular.ok, ...) : 
  0 (non-NA) cases`

Comment: @akrun Here on my computer this error is not appearing. Also, it looks like you're using the `lm.fit()` function, which I haven't used. Could you please be more specific about where the error is?

Comment: Here, is the error `tmp <- subset(df, Group == 'B');

obj1 <- lm(y ~ x, tmp);
 segmented(obj1, seg.Z = ~ x)#Error in lm.fit(x, y, offset = offset, singular.ok = singular.ok, ...) : 
  0 (non-NA) cases`. If you do the same with `Group == 'A'` it works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to wrap with `tryCatch` and return a NA for possible errors

```
library(dplyr)
out <- df %>% 
    nest_by(Group) %>%
    mutate(my.lm = list(lm(y ~ x, data = data)),
        my.seg = list(tryCatch(segmented(my.lm, seg.Z = ~ x),
         error = function(e) list(NA))))
```

-output

```
> out
# A tibble: 2 x 4
# Rowwise:  Group
  Group               data my.lm  my.seg    
  <fct> <list<tibble[,2]>> <list> <list>    
1 A               [11 × 2] <lm>   <segmentd>
2 B               [11 × 2] <lm>   <list [1]>
> out$my.seg
[[1]]
Call: segmented.lm(obj = my.lm, seg.Z = ~x)

Meaningful coefficients of the linear terms:
(Intercept)            x         U1.x  
    0.03333      0.30000     -0.27488  

Estimated Break-Point(s):
psi1.x  
 2.691  

[[2]]
[[2]][[1]]
[1] NA
```